# wha's the difference in the two kind of gradle task defination?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

1. ```
   tasks.named('bootBuildImage') {

   }
   ```
2. ```
   bootBuildImage {

   }
   ```

I find the source for the first usage in [spring boot gradle plugin document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.5/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.custom-image-builder) , but I cannot find the source for the  second one. And what difference between them?

I want to know source for the second usage, I cannot find in both gradle official document and spring boot gradle official document.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Boot Gradle Plugin established the second usage u r curious about. It offers a condensed configuration DSL (Domain-Specific Language) that enables you to more quickly configure the tasks of the plugin. This DSL is not a typical Gradle syntax; it is unique to the Spring Boot plugin.

The Spring Boot Gradle Plugin repository on GitHub should contains the source code for the second application. Depending on the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin version you are using, the precise location of the source code may change. The repository can be searched through to find the right version.  Hope this helps